# I need to install jdk 1.4 for legacy program in linux ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk1.4

I've tried to install java 1.4 for an old program and download it from Oracle official web site. But the content directory structure of the tar.Z file are a bit messy, and I try to put it in Eclipse(via >Window>Preferences>Installed JRE> ) but it didn't work.
The directories inside jdk 1.4:
[image]

That was the folder structure from the download version and it's very diferent from the original one's. For example, in 'SUNWj3rt' there is a java exec in SUNJ3rt>reloc>j2se>bin folder, and another folder SUNJ3rt>reloc>j2se>jre>bin as well and the SDK apparently is in SUNWj3dev>reloc/j2se/bin (javac and others), but I tried in many ways to put it in Eclipse but didn't recognize via 'JRE_home' or via 'Extenal JARs' options. Anyone else knows how to deal with it or if there is another way to install jdk 1.4 instead of ORACLE website?

Comment: Do not use images for textual information here. Do a listing of the tar contents in the command line.

Comment: Why do you need to install 1.4 for a legacy program? The latest JRE should run it fine

Comment: The Oracle site only has Java 1.4 for Solaris (which is not Linux). Most Java programs should be compatible with the current Java 21 and if not try Java 8.

Comment: @greg-449 I use jdk11 and when I put it in Eclipse the compiler complains: 'The type java.awt.Component cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type javax.swing.JComponent, ComponentList.java' in line 1 from this class, and when I configure as 1.4, the compiler complains that 'taget is 1.2' but it compiles against 1.4 that requires version 9 in runtime.

Comment: java.awt.Component is in every release of Java. Something is wrong with your setup but there isn't enough information here to say what.

Comment: *@greg-449 I use jdk11 and when I put it in Eclipse ... requires version 9 in runtime.* That's all incredibly confusing. You really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of something you think you need 1.4 to compile and run against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you downloaded a tar containing a version of the JDK 1.4 for Solaris instead of Linux.

Note that if the old Java 1.4 distribution will run correctly in a much newer Linux distribution is up to you to test.

Comment: Perhaps it is from Solaris! But I dindn't find anything diferent in Oracle Website. Do you know if there is other places that we can download Java 1.4? Tks!

Comment: Really? literally is the first link I got searching for "java download jdk 1.4"